# Testing for a directory in Node results in pending Promise in developer tools console

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am trying to test for the existence of a directory in an Electron app. I’m trying it out in the console while the code is paused.

Here is the sample code:

```js
fsp = require('fs').promises;
serverRoot = '/something/';
fsp
.open(serverRoot)
.then(() => {
    console.log('ok');
    return 1;
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log('oops');
    return 0;
});
```

The console displays:

> `Promise {<pending>}`

I don’t understand why I don’t get one of the `console.log()` messages. I have successfully tried similar code to write to a file if it doesn’t exists (using `stat`, but `stat` doesn’t make any difference here).

Is this an issue with using the developer tools?

I know that I can try with `async / await` but I want to understand what I’m doing wrong here.

Comment: Sounds like the console is just showing you the evaluation of the `fsp.open().then().catch()` expression (which is a promise)

Comment: Are you saying that you *never* get the logs? Or just that you would have expected to get the logs immediately?

Comment: @Bergi Never. It’s still pending …

Comment: Problem would be with "*while the code is paused*". Resume execution and it should log.

Comment: @Bergi You’re absolutely right. That meant my test code couldn’t use the variables from the paused code, but at least I can see where the promise was hanging. Thanks.